# Google cloud OAuth api verification

Tags: cloud, google, oauth, verification

We submitted our Google cloud OAuth api verification on 21-Nov-2022 and seeing the same status "Verification in progress" for long time.

There is no way to contact support about this inquiry. Is there a way to check if there is something wrong with our submission? Anyone can help?

Comment: Any update on the status of your OAuth verification? Are you trying to register an application and obtaining the client credentials?